# Problem rendering cube using DirectX 11

Tags: rendering, directx11

I'm toying with DirectX 11 and am trying to render a simple cube, but I can't seem to get anything to show (except the clear color, which is a good sign I suppose...)

Everything seems to be working, every calls into D3D I make succeeds.

When I inspect my vertex buffers/index buffers/etc using VS2012, they show me the right data.

However, when I inspect the Input Assembler stage, when I should be seeing a cube, I see.. nothing. So I guess it's not a shader problem at least...

I joined a .vslog that can be opened with VS2012 and shows the different D3D calls I make and makes it possible to see the content of the different D3D objects. I imagine the problem lies in my vertex buffer/index buffer/input layout because it happens at the input assembler stage, but I just can't see the problem :(

Any idea?

Here's the .vsglog file:
http://www.mediafire.com/?q3q77mlnuopj3g0

Here's the project file:
http://www.mediafire.com/?sz4rc9qx31lmnw7

Here's the code without any error checking or cleanup:

```
// RenderTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <fstream>

#include <d3d11.h>
#include <dxgi1_2.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib") 
#pragma comment (lib, "dxgi.lib") 

using namespace DirectX;

int g_Width = 800;
int g_Height = 600;

HWND g_HWND;

IDXGISwapChain*         g_pSwapChain;
ID3D11Device*           g_pDevice;
ID3D11DeviceContext*    g_pDeviceContext;
ID3D11RenderTargetView* g_pBackBuffer;

ID3D11Buffer*           g_pVertexBuffer;
ID3D11Buffer*           g_pIndexBuffer;
ID3D11Buffer*           g_pConstantBuffer;

ID3D11Texture2D*         g_pDepthStencilBuffer;
ID3D11DepthStencilState* g_pDepthStencilState;
ID3D11DepthStencilView*  g_pDepthStencilView;

ID3D11InputLayout*      g_pInputLayout;
ID3D11VertexShader*     g_pVertexShader;
ID3D11PixelShader*      g_pPixelShader;

char*                   g_pVSContent;
size_t                  g_VSSize;

char*                   g_pPSContent;
size_t                  g_PSSize;

#define HR(c)                       (void) ((!!(SUCCEEDED(c))) || \
  (1 != _CrtDbgReport(_CRT_ASSERT, __FILE__, __LINE__, NULL, #c)) || \
  (__debugbreak(), 0))

struct MatrixBuffer
{
    XMMATRIX WorldMatrix;
    XMMATRIX ViewMatrix;
    XMMATRIX ProjectionMatrix;
};

void CreateAWindow(void);
void CreateInputLayout(void);
void CreateIndexBuffer(void);
void CreateVertexBuffer(void);
void CreateConstantBuffer(void);
void CreateVertexShader(void);
void CreatePixelShader(void);
void CreateDepthStencilBuffer(void);
void LoadShadersContent(void);




int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CreateAWindow();

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd = {};
    scd.BufferCount = 1;
    scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    scd.OutputWindow = g_HWND;
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    scd.Windowed = TRUE;

    HR(D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(nullptr,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        nullptr,
        D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG,
        nullptr,
        0,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &scd,
        &g_pSwapChain,
        &g_pDevice,
        nullptr,
        &g_pDeviceContext));

    ID3D11Texture2D *pBackBufferTexture;
    HR(g_pSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBufferTexture));
    HR(g_pDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBufferTexture, nullptr, &g_pBackBuffer));
    pBackBufferTexture->Release();

    CreateDepthStencilBuffer();

    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport = {};
    viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    viewport.Width = (FLOAT)g_Width;
    viewport.Height = (FLOAT)g_Height;

    g_pDeviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    g_pDeviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(g_pDepthStencilState, 1);
    g_pDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &g_pBackBuffer, g_pDepthStencilView);



    CreatePixelShader();
    CreateVertexShader();

    CreateVertexBuffer();
    CreateIndexBuffer();
    CreateConstantBuffer();
    CreateInputLayout();

    g_pDeviceContext->PSSetShader(g_pPixelShader, nullptr, 0);
    g_pDeviceContext->VSSetShader(g_pVertexShader, nullptr, 0);
    g_pDeviceContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &g_pConstantBuffer);

    unsigned int zero = 0;
    unsigned int stride = 12;
    g_pDeviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &g_pVertexBuffer, &stride, &zero);
    g_pDeviceContext->IASetIndexBuffer(g_pIndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
    g_pDeviceContext->IASetInputLayout(g_pInputLayout);
    g_pDeviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    ID3D11RasterizerState * g_pRasterState;

    D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC rasterizerState;
    rasterizerState.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
    rasterizerState.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_NONE;
    rasterizerState.FrontCounterClockwise = true;
    rasterizerState.DepthBias = false;
    rasterizerState.DepthBiasClamp = 0;
    rasterizerState.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0;
    rasterizerState.DepthClipEnable = false;
    rasterizerState.ScissorEnable = false;
    rasterizerState.MultisampleEnable = false;
    rasterizerState.AntialiasedLineEnable = false;
    HR(g_pDevice->CreateRasterizerState( &rasterizerState, &g_pRasterState));
    g_pDeviceContext->RSSetState(g_pRasterState);

    MSG msg = {};
    while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
        // wait for the next message in the queue, store the result in 'msg'
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)> 0)
        {
            // translate keystroke messages into the right format
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            // send the message to the WindowProc function
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        float clearColor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f };
        g_pDeviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(g_pBackBuffer, clearColor);

        g_pDeviceContext->DrawIndexed(36, 0, 0);

        g_pSwapChain->Present(0, 0);
    }


    return 0;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // sort through and find what code to run for the message given
    switch(message)
    {
        // this message is read when the window is closed
        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                // close the application entirely
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            } break;
    }

    // Handle any messages the switch statement didn't
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

void CreateAWindow(void)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {};
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszClassName = _T("TestClass");

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    auto style = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;

    RECT windowRect = {0};
    windowRect.right = g_Width;
    windowRect.bottom = g_Height;
    AdjustWindowRect(&windowRect, style, FALSE);

    auto x = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - g_Width) / 2;
    auto y = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - g_Height) / 2;

    g_HWND = CreateWindowEx(0,
                _T("TestClass"),    // name of the window class
                _T("Test"),   // title of the window
                style,    // window style
                x,    // TODO: x-position of the window
                y,    // TODO: y-position of the window
                windowRect.right - windowRect.left,    // g_Width of the window
                windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top,    // g_Height of the window
                nullptr,    // we have no parent window, NULL
                nullptr,    // we aren't using menus, NULL
                GetModuleHandle(nullptr),    // application handle
                nullptr); 

    ShowWindow(g_HWND, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
}

void LoadShadersContent(void)
{
    if (g_pVSContent)
        return;

    std::ifstream isVS("SimpleVertexShader.cso", std::ios::binary);
    isVS.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
    g_VSSize = (size_t)isVS.tellg();
    g_pVSContent = new char[g_VSSize];
    isVS.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
    isVS.read(g_pVSContent, g_VSSize);
    isVS.close();

    std::ifstream isPS("SimplePixelShader.cso", std::ios::binary);
    isPS.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
    g_PSSize = (size_t)isPS.tellg();
    g_pPSContent = new char[g_PSSize];
    isPS.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
    isPS.read(g_pPSContent, g_PSSize);
    isPS.close();
}

void CreatePixelShader(void)
{
    LoadShadersContent();
    HR(g_pDevice->CreatePixelShader(g_pPSContent, g_PSSize, nullptr, &g_pPixelShader));
}

void CreateVertexShader(void)
{
    LoadShadersContent();
    HR(g_pDevice->CreateVertexShader(g_pVSContent, g_VSSize, nullptr, &g_pVertexShader));
}

void CreateConstantBuffer(void)
{
    MatrixBuffer constants = {};
    constants.ProjectionMatrix = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(XM_PIDIV4, (float)g_Width / g_Height, 1.0f, 1000.0f);
    constants.ViewMatrix = XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    constants.WorldMatrix = XMMatrixIdentity();

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC desc = {};
    desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(MatrixBuffer);
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA data = {};
    data.pSysMem = &constants;

    HR(g_pDevice->CreateBuffer(&desc, &data, &g_pConstantBuffer));
}

void CreateVertexBuffer(void)
{
    XMFLOAT3 vertices[8];

    //Top
    vertices[0] = XMFLOAT3(-0.5f, 1.0f, -0.5f);
    vertices[1] = XMFLOAT3(-0.5f, 1.0f, 0.5f);
    vertices[2] = XMFLOAT3(0.5f, 1.0f, 0.5f);
    vertices[3] = XMFLOAT3(0.5f, 1.0f, -0.5f);

    //Bottom
    vertices[4] = XMFLOAT3(-0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f);
    vertices[5] = XMFLOAT3(-0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    vertices[6] = XMFLOAT3(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    vertices[7] = XMFLOAT3(0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f);

    // Vertex buffer
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC desc;
    ZeroMemory(&desc, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));
    desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(vertices);
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA data;
    ZeroMemory(&data, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));
    data.pSysMem = &vertices;

    HR(g_pDevice->CreateBuffer(&desc, &data, &g_pVertexBuffer));
}

void CreateIndexBuffer(void)
{
    int indices[36];

    // Top
    indices[0] = 0; indices[1] = 1; indices[2] = 2;
    indices[3] = 0; indices[4] = 2; indices[5] = 3;

    // Bottom
    indices[6] = 4; indices[7]  = 5; indices[8]  = 6;
    indices[9] = 4; indices[10] = 6; indices[11] = 7;

    // Left
    indices[12] = 4; indices[13] = 5; indices[14] = 1;
    indices[15] = 4; indices[16] = 1; indices[17] = 0;

    // Right
    indices[18] = 6; indices[19] = 7; indices[20] = 3;
    indices[21] = 6; indices[22] = 3; indices[23] = 2;

    // Front
    indices[24] = 4; indices[25] = 0; indices[26] = 3;
    indices[27] = 4; indices[28] = 3; indices[29] = 7;

    // Back
    indices[30] = 6; indices[31] = 2; indices[32] = 1;
    indices[33] = 6; indices[34] = 1; indices[35] = 5;

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC desc = {};
    desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(indices);
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA data;
    ZeroMemory(&data, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));
    data.pSysMem = &indices;

    HR(g_pDevice->CreateBuffer(&desc, &data, &g_pIndexBuffer));
}

void CreateInputLayout(void)
{   
    LoadShadersContent();
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] =
    {
        { "SV_POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,    0, 0,  D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
    }; 

    HR(g_pDevice->CreateInputLayout(ied, 1, g_pVSContent, g_VSSize, &g_pInputLayout));
}

void CreateDepthStencilBuffer(void)
{
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC descDepth;
    descDepth.Width = g_Width;
    descDepth.Height = g_Height;
    descDepth.MipLevels = 1;
    descDepth.ArraySize = 1;
    descDepth.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    descDepth.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    descDepth.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    descDepth.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    descDepth.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    descDepth.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    descDepth.MiscFlags = 0;
    HR(g_pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&descDepth, NULL, &g_pDepthStencilBuffer));

    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC dsDesc;
    // Depth test parameters
    dsDesc.DepthEnable = true;
    dsDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
    dsDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;

    // Stencil test parameters
    dsDesc.StencilEnable = true;
    dsDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
    dsDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;

    // Stencil operations if pixel is front-facing
    dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
    dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

    // Stencil operations if pixel is back-facing
    dsDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    dsDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
    dsDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    dsDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

    // Create depth stencil state
    g_pDevice->CreateDepthStencilState(&dsDesc, &g_pDepthStencilState);

    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC descDSV = {};
    descDSV.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    descDSV.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    descDSV.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
    HRESULT hr;
    HR(hr = g_pDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(g_pDepthStencilBuffer, // Depth stencil texture
                                        &descDSV, // Depth stencil desc
                                        &g_pDepthStencilView));
}
```

The Vertex Shader:

```
cbuffer MatrixBuffer
{
    matrix worldMatrix;
    matrix viewMatrix;
    matrix projectionMatrix;
};

struct VS_INPUT
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
};

struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

PS_INPUT main(VS_INPUT input)
{
    PS_INPUT output;

    // Change the position vector to be 4 units for proper matrix calculations.
    input.position.w = 1.0f;

    // Calculate the position of the vertex against the world, view, and projection matrices.
    output.position = mul(input.position, worldMatrix);
    output.position = mul(output.position, viewMatrix);
    output.position = mul(output.position, projectionMatrix);

    // Store the input color for the pixel shader to use.
    output.color = float4(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);

    return output;
}
```

And finally, the pixel shader:

```
struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

float4 main(PS_INPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
    return input.color;
}
```

Comment: You may find you get a more useful response if you post some code!

Comment: In your input layout, you use the `POSITION` semantic - which is technically a D3D9 semantic. You can still use it in D3D10+, but I've seen it mess things up a few times before. Try using `SV_POSITION` instead (both in the input layout and vertex shader input declaration) and see if that helps.

Comment: @Goz I thought about it, but there's so many code spread across so many classes that I doubt it would be more useful than the .vsglog file :/

Comment: @melak47: no go, but thanks for the info!

Comment: @Kevin: Well sorry then  Idon't run windows 8 so I can't do anything with a vsglog ... If you can get a pix dump I might be able to help ...

Comment: @Goz: well instead I'll to start a new project and dump all my rendering code in the main and see if I can get that working, and if not, post the code :)

Comment: I put some code now! :D

Comment: `XMMatrixPerspectiveFovXH`'s first parameter is the *vertical* FOV *in radians* , not degrees, so try something like Pi/4 there (`DirectX::XM_PIDIV4`) and see if that helps.

Comment: Ah! thanks for the catch, but sadly, it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: Try changing your cull direction

Comment: @Kevin try using http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge

Comment: @Tetrad: Well I never set a password for that duplicate account so I guess I can't do the steps outlined since I can't login. Anyway, doesn't really matter if they are merged or not I guess

Comment: @Kevin did you click on the link in the "If you have lost access to your duplicate account, please click here to fill out the form." sentence?

Comment: @Tetrad: I did, but it says I need to change the About Me to "merge me", but I can't do that as I can't log in that account. I tried to use the account recovery with the email I used, but it tries to recover this account instead of the temporary one.

Comment: @Kevin mods no longer have the power to merge accounts anymore, I'd recommend filling out the contact form here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a quick flick through the major problem I see is in your SetVertexBuffers call:

```
g_pDeviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &g_pVertexBuffer, &zero, &zero);
```

Basically you are setting the vertex buffer stride to 0.  Your stride is actually 12 bytes.

```
UINT stride = 12;
g_pDeviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &g_pVertexBuffer, &stride, &zero);
```

This is something the debug runtime ought to report to you if you create your device and swap chain with the correct flag:

```
HR(D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL,
        D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG,
        NULL,
        0,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &scd,
        &g_pSwapChain,
        &g_pDevice,
        NULL,
        &g_pDeviceContext));
```

Use it to save yourself loads of time tracking down bugs.

Its all worth bearing in mind that rendering a cube without a depth buffer will cause polygons to overlap each other in weird ways.  You should definitely create and bind a DepthStencilView ...

**Edit:** Looking again its possible your view matrix is actually looking away from the object (I can't be 100% on that as I haven't gone through all the maths).

Try using [XMMatrixLookAtLH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.matrix.xmmatrixlookatlh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

```
constants.ViewMatrix = XMMatrixLookAtLH( XMVector( 0, 0, -50.0f ), XMVector( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ), XMVector( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ) );
```

Comment: I tried with the debug flag, but it doesn't warn me about the stride. Fixing the stride does show me the cube in the debug view, but not on screen. It's like the pixel shader doesn't run :(
http://i.imgur.com/g0ZTyiD.png

Comment: @Kevin: Edited my answer.

Comment: I'm not home so I can't try, but I don't think it is the problem - in the image, you can see the cube after the vertex shader ran and it's there, a bit far away, in the middle of the screen :(

Comment: @kevin: Move the camera closer to the cube?

Comment: I don't think it's too far, you can see it in the vertex shader so it should be visible on screen

Comment: @Kevin: well it IS visible on the screen ... a 1 unit wide cube from 50 units away is going to be pretty small ...

Comment: Well if you look at the screenshot I had posted (http://i.imgur.com/g0ZTyiD.png), it is not that small and I should be able to see it no problem. Using -2 instead of -50, I can see it almost full-screen on the debugger, but still nothing appears on-screen. I even tried to disable back-face culling in case, but nothing seems to work

Comment: @Kevin:  Have you tried adding a depth stencil view?

Comment: Yes, still doesn't work :/ whyyyyy

Comment: OK. 3 things: 1 - I wasn't clearing the depth-stencil view before every frame. 2 - Apparently it's XMMatrixLookAtRH that needs to be used and not LH. I thought D3D11 used left-handed coordinates. Whatever. 3 - When setting the matrices in the constant buffer, they need to be transposed beforehand...

Comment: @Kevin: Did that sort your issues?

Comment: Ouch, looks like I got beaten by 15 minutes! Glad you managed to figure it out, though.

Comment: @Kevin: DirectX is left-handed. But assuming you set the view position's Z coordinate to -1.0, your camera would be facing away from the cube. XMMatrixLookAtRH would correct for the error and point it toward the cube. XMMatrixLookAtLH with the Z coordinate as 1.0 would give you the same effect.

Comment: @DanielRowe: Wouldn't my suggestion of using `XMMatrixLookAtLH` have sorted that?

Comment: @Goz: Right, your suggestion should've worked fine, which makes me think he had an offsetting error somewhere if RH worked and LH was facing the wrong way.

Comment: @DanielRowe: Also its worth noting that directx is not LH or RH ... its >your< system that is LH or RH ... LH or RH is a pretty simple matrix modification.  If you want to work LH do so ... equally with RH ... Learning linear algebra will teach you far more :)

Comment: @Goz: Exactly - handedness is just a matter of how the default API generates matrices. But you can build your matrices however you want as long as they give you the right position in clip space :)

Comment: @Goz: No, your solution wouldn't have worked using XMMatrixLookAtLH without a transpose. Maybe the handedness is my choice, but not how matrices are to be read from memory by the shader (or at least, the default behavior which uses column-major matrices)
[link 1 saying HLSH is column-major by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509634(v=vs.85).aspx#Matrix_Ordering) [link 2 saying if shader uses column-major matrices, you need to transpose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729728(v=vs.85).aspx#Use_DXMath_with_D3D)

Answer (score 2):

You're not clearing your depth buffer, so every pixel gets rejected when you try to draw your cube.

In your message loop, clear the depth stencil view as such:

```
g_pDeviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(g_pBackBuffer, clearColor);
g_pDeviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView(g_pDepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0xFF);
```

The 1.0f indicates that you're clearing the depth buffer with the maximum value. Since you have your depth comparison test set to D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS, the cube's fragments will pass through unharmed.

Unfortunately you have a new problem - you'll see a gray stripe across the top of your screen instead of your cube from the proper perspective. I'm guessing your constant buffer isn't being properly referenced by your shader. Replacing the "bottom" vertices' Y coordinates with -1.0 extends the gray stripe to the bottom of the screen, which means your vertex values are passing through your vertex shader totally unmodified (clip space extends from -1.0 to 1.0 on the X and Y axes). I'd take a look at the shader but you only supplied compiled binaries. Hopefully this gives you a place to start.

On a related note, I don't think you're setting up your view matrix correctly. Unless you're taking a math shortcut, I think you're misunderstanding what the view matrix is (the inverse of your camera's transformation matrix). Replace this:

```
constants.ViewMatrix = XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
```

with something like this:

```
DirectX::FXMVECTOR eyePos = { 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f };
DirectX::FXMVECTOR focusPos = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
DirectX::FXMVECTOR up = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
constants.ViewMatrix = XMMatrixLookAtLH( eyePos, focusPos, up );
```

But since your shader isn't using the constant buffer, no changes I'm making to any of the constant buffer's values are having any effect. Intel GPA shows that your constant buffer is making it onto the GPU, so I think your shader just isn't using the data.

Comment: Why are you saying I'm not using the constant buffer? ie:      `output.position = mul(output.position, viewMatrix)` uses the viewMatrix from the constant buffer

Comment: It was just a guess since none of the matrices looked like they were getting applied; sounds like you figured out that the data needed to be transposed, which makes sense too.

Answer (score -3):

I know this is already answered but I think this will help some people. Try downloading Windows 8.1. To download it with Visual Studio 2015 just do Control Panel->Programs and Features(Add/Remove Program)->Right click VS2015 and select change. Then check Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1. Then retarget your project.

That worked for me, but I'm using DirectX 11.2 which is for Windows 8.1.

I'm using the tutorial from here: http://www.directxtutorial.com/

Comment: People won't download Windows 8 just to solve this issue.

Comment: You don't have to download windows 8, that's not what I meant. It's an SDK "Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1"